# How to pass data when calling another Windows-Phone App?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am starting in WP development but I already got the following situation.
I have my app and I need other apps to call it passing data/parameters that I will specify.
For example:
App X will call and open my app, passing parameters like id, name and age.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Define a [URI association](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_URIassociations) for your app.
To do so add content like this to the app's manifest file:

```
<Extensions>
  <Protocol Name="myapp" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

Define a class that derives from `UriMapperBase` to handle incoming URIs and register right after the call to `RootFrame.Navigated + = /*...*/` by doing this:

```
RootFrame.UriMapper = new MyPersonalUriMapper();
```

Other apps can open your app by doing something like this:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new System.Uri("myapp:4711/Luciano/24"));
```

You can parse this URI in your `UriMapper` to open the page you wanted with ID=4711, Name=Luciano and Age=24.